# GAE app runs fine locally but fails with a 500 server error when deployed to app engine

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I have a simple python GAE app where python determines if the request is from a phone or other. Depending on the result, one page is served vs. another. The app runs fine locally (dev_appserver.py). When deployed to GAE, I get a 500 server error.

If I decouple the two apps they each run fine locally and when deployed to GAE. Some additional detail about the apps is they also use angular and jquery.  Here's the simple python that is supposed to server the 2 different pages depending on if the request is from a phone or other...

```
import webapp2

Called from application at bottom

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        #INDEX_HTML = open('app/index_1.html').read()
        #self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML)

        INDEX_HTML_1 = open('app/index_1.html').read()
        INDEX_HTML_2 = open('app/index_2.html').read()

        if "Android" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "iPhone" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "iPad" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "iPod" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "BlackBerry" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "IEMobile" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)
        elif "Opera Mini" in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_1)

        else:
          self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML_2)
```

called from app.yaml

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs

Comment: You might try logging `self.request.headers["User-Agent"]`.  Might be a key error.  Safer to use `self.request.headers.get('User-Agent', '')`

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow. I thought I would get an email when a comment was left. I didn't and just checked the site. Thank you both for the feedback. I checked the logs (new to GAE) and the file that was to load was not found. Clearly, that was the main issue. I will also try the other suggestion.